# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds while testing a char for if it is an int

Tags: java, tostring, arrays

Alright, guys, I'm trying to get a basic hang on Java and I figured I would make something a bit more complicated than usual. What I have in this method is an attempt to first check if the first character can be an int, and if it is, I want to see how far that number will go in the input (so if the user inputted 455+60, I'd want to pull out the 455 and stop at the +).

For some reason, if the input is 500t, it will work fine. But if the index ends after the number (say the input is just 500), it has a problem. I am thinking the for loop keeps going for some reason. Can someone tell me where I messed up? I added an if statement to see if I could stop it, but to no avail.

```
public void init(){
    int chars = 0;
    /*
     * Input fancy intro here.
     */
    clearArray();
    String uInput = getInput();
    rawInput=uInput.toCharArray();
    cleanArray(rawInput);
    try{Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(rawInput[0]));
    boolean isNum = true;
    for(int i=0;isNum==true;i++){
        if(i != rawInput.length){
        try{Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(rawInput[i]));}
        catch (NumberFormatException s){
            isNum = false;
            chars = i;
            System.out.println("The number has: "+chars+" characters.");
        }
        }
        }       
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException s){
        System.out.println("What is this madness?");

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you avoid asking for `rawInput[rawInput.length]`:

```
if(i != rawInput.length)
```

... but you *do* keep going for the next iteration.

Is there any reason you can't just do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rawInput.length && isNum; i++)
```

? I would also suggest using [`Character.isDigit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) or a custom check rather than converting each character to a string, then parsing it and catching an exception.

Note that `Character.isDigit` will return `true` for non-ASCII digits, which you may not want. You quite possibly just want a simple check of:

```
char c = rawInput[i];
if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
    isNum = false;
}
```

Also note that a regular expression may well be a better solution for this...

Oh, and if you've got an empty string, that will count as a number at the moment...

Comment: Alright, thanks. I did have to change your for loop in the middle to be rawInput.length && isNum, not sure if we are just using different versions on that one.

Comment: @Signify: No, that was just a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this by adding an extra check in your for loop to see if you are at the end of the string.  Try:

```
for(int i=0;isNum==true && i<rawInput.length;i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public int countDigits(String input) {
    int digitsCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))) {
            ++digitsCount;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return digitsCount;
}
```